# Div displays as table on desktop, but want to stack divs for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm fairly new to coding HTML and CSS, and I'm looking for a starting point with responsive design that will help me finish a project I'm working on.

I have essentially used divs to create a two-column table (using div style="display: table;") and then divs for each column and row. In each row, there is an icon in the left column and text in the right column.

I understand the concept around media queries and have written the queries that I want based on screen sizes.

What I need help with is a starting point for what I need to write inside the queries - essentially resizing the divs and also displaying the divs differently (I imagine with floats) so that I can have the icons in the left column display above the icons in the right column. Basically, I want to stack the divs. I hope that makes sense. I'm not entirely sure where to start. I appreciate any and all help in advance.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div style="display: table;">
<!--First row-->
<div id="tr1" style="display: table-row;">
    <div class="icon" style="display: table-cell;">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E_DoZ3hZPZw/Uwl7yLn50_I/AAAAAAAAGr8/XpmeP14aphA/s1600/green.gif" width="300"></a></div>        

    <div class="words" style="display: table-cell;">
        <h1>Text title</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p></div>
</div>

<!--Second row-->
<div id="tr2" style="display: table-row;">
        <div class="icon" style="display: table-cell;">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg" width="300"></a></div>
            <div class="words" style="display: table-cell;">
            <h1>Another text title</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p></div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    .icon {position: relative; }

.words {position: static;
        vertical-align: middle;}

/* Mobile: Max Size for Mobile Device */
@media (max-width: 639px){

}
```

Comment: First, don't use inline styles.  You need to move the `display` styles to your css, and then in your media queries you can force the display styles to be different, so that they stack.  Also, remove the `display: table` from the parent div - when using `table-cell`, the browsers are smart enough to infer that style, and it's one less thing to deal with when you get to your media queries.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I didn't realize browsers infer the table-cell style. That definitely helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basics of what I've done in [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LG57F/):

1. Indented.  Reading code that isn't indented is difficult, and leads to errors.
2. Removed inline styles.
3. Set the CSS for the third-level divs to be `display: table-cell`.  Note that this selector should / could be replaced with a class instead.
4. Added the css to your media query to cause them to "stack" as requested.

Here's the revised code for your reference:

```
<!-- Removed the "display: table" - not necessary -->
<div>
    <!--First row-->
    <!-- Remove the "display: table-row" - not necessary -->
    <div id="tr1">
            <!-- Remove the "display: table-cell" - moved to css -->
        <div class="icon">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E_DoZ3hZPZw/Uwl7yLn50_I/AAAAAAAAGr8/XpmeP14aphA/s1600/green.gif" width="300"></a>
        </div>        
        <div class="words">
            <h1>Text title</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Second row-->
    <div id="tr2">
        <div class="icon">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg" width="300"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="words" style="display: table-cell;">
            <h1>Another text title</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* this selects third-level divs */
div > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.icon {
    position: relative; 
}

.words {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Mobile: Max Size for Mobile Device */
@media (max-width: 639px) {
    /* change the display to block for stacking */
    div > div > div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for all of your help - I think I've learned my lesson on not indenting my code properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is all about rewriting. So here is something that could inspure you.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<!--First row-->
<div id="tr1" class="row">
<div class="icon">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E_DoZ3hZPZw/Uwl7yLn50_I/AAAAAAAAGr8/XpmeP14aphA/s1600/green.gif"></a></div>        
<div class="words">
    <h1>Text title</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p></div>
</div>
<!--Second row-->
<div id="tr2" class="row">
    <div class="icon">
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg"></a></div>
        <div class="words">
        <h1>Another text title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet fermentum arcu, elementum dapibus nulla. Donec quis libero in risus gravida rutrum. Vestibulum vitae.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
.icon {
position: relative;
display: table-cell; }
.icon a img {
    width: 300px;
}.words {
position: static;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
/* Mobile: Max Size for Mobile Device */
@media (max-width: 639px){
.wrapper,
.row,
.words,
.icon {
    display: block;
}
.words,
.icon {
    text-align: center;
}
.icon a img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
}
```

Hope it helps.